# Half day Calendar with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, user-interface, ggplot2, shiny, calendar

Thanks to this website: [Calendar With ggplot2](http://www.roymfrancis.com/calendar-plot-with-ggplot2/) , I succeed to create a calendar like this :
[image: Model of work calendar]

I try to create a calendar to list availabilities of people of a group for example. But the problem is I would like to split this calendar in half a day  (morning/afternoon) like this :
[image: What i wanted.]
Is it possible to split one day in two ? Either like 8 of march (Mars) like this post :
[Splot color rectangle in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22107666/generating-split-color-rectangles-from-ggplot2-geom-raster) or in diagonal like 14 of march ?

For example :
`dfr$comment[dfr$date>=as.Date('2019-03-08 12:00:00') & dfr$date<=as.Date('2019-03-14 12:00:00')+1] <- "Absent"` applies this chart.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can't you just `rep` dates with  `each=2` and `paste( dt, c("am", "pm")`?

Comment: I just don't understand totally where I must to apply the code and how it works ?
The actual code devided in 3 parts :
DF with the date range :
`dfr        <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'),as.Date('2019-03-31'),by=1))`
With the week, day and months.
A second part with the dates like away, sick etc :
`dfr$comment[dfr$date>=as.Date('2019-01-01') & dfr$date<=as.Date('2019-01-04')+1] <- "Absent"`
And:
The factor and the ggplot part with calendar (geom, scale, theme etc.)